# How to fetch a list of internal members from outer list?

Tags: c#, .net, list

I have a Class something similar to like below

```
class OuterClass
{
    public InnerClass InnerObject{get;set;}
    ////Some more properties and methods
}
```

Now in another class I have two lists, one of `OuterClass` objects and one of `InnerClass` objects. And I want the list of `InnerClass` objects to be populated from the property `InnerObject` of objects in `OuterClass` list. 
I can achieve this by iterating through `OuterClass` list and populating the `InnerClass` list. However, this needs to be taken care anytime `OuterClass` list is modified.

```
class AnotherClass
{
    private List<OuterClass> OuterClassList{get;set;}
    private List<InnerClass> InnerClassList{get;set;}

    public void InsertOuterClassObject(OuterClass outerClassObject)
    {
        this.OuterClassList.Add(outerClassObject);
        this.PopulateInnerClassList();
    }

    private void PopulateInnerClassList()
    {
        this.InnerClassList = new List<InnerClass>();
        foreach(var object in this.OuterClassList)
        {
            this.InnerClassList.Add(object.InnerObject);
         }
     }

     ////More operations to be performed on OuterClassList
 }
```

Is there some other way I can make sure that the `InnerClassList` is correctly synced with `OuterClassList` rather than having to iterate and populate and also to make sure the method `PopulateInnerClassList()` is surely called when necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample code suggests the `InnerClassList` should only reflect state of the `OuterClassList` and not be maintained independently. If this is the case, you may build the inner list on the fly:

```
private List<InnerClass> InnerClassList => OuterClassList.Select(x => x.InnerObject).ToList();
```

And if `InnerClassList`'s usage pattern is limited to iterating through it, you may change its type to `IEnumerable<InnerClass>` thus avoiding performance degradation on long lists:

```
private IEnumerable<InnerClass> InnerClassList => OuterClassList.Select(x => x.InnerObject);
```

So the resulting list maintenance code may look like this:

```
class AnotherClass
{
    private List<OuterClass> OuterClassList { get; } = new List<OuterClass>();

    private IEnumerable<InnerClass> InnerClassList => OuterClassList.Select(x => x.InnerObject);

    public void InsertOuterClassObject(OuterClass outerClassObject)
    {
        this.OuterClassList.Add(outerClassObject);
    }

    ////More operations to be performed on OuterClassList
}
```

Note: I also changed definition of `OuterClassList` to ensure it's always instantiated. Granted it's a private property, changing it to a read-only once-initialized object won't break `AnotherClass` API and make internal manipulation easier.

Comment: Just don't ever call `InnerClassList.Add(item)` and expect it to do anything.

Answer (score 1):

Try to see if it meets your needs.

```
public class AnotherClass
{
    private List<OuterClass> _OuterClassList;
    private List<InnerClass> _InnerClassList;
    private List<OuterClass> OuterClassList {
        get { return _OuterClassList; }
        set
        {
            _OuterClassList = value;
            InnerClassList = value.Select(a => a.InnerObject).ToList();
        }
    }
    private List<InnerClass> InnerClassList { get { return _InnerClassList; } set { InnerClassList = value; } }

    public void InsertOuterClassObject(OuterClass outerClassObject)
    {
        this.OuterClassList.Add(outerClassObject);
        this.PopulateInnerClassList();
    }

    private void PopulateInnerClassList()
    {
        this.InnerClassList = new List<InnerClass>();
        foreach (var item in this.OuterClassList)
        {
            this.InnerClassList.Add(item.InnerObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need InnerClassList I think, look this:

```
private List<OuterClass> OuterClassList { get; set; }//initialize in constructor.

internal class OuterClass
{
    public InnerClass InnerObject { get; set; }

    public OuterClass(int num) => InnerObject = new InnerClass(num);
}

internal class InnerClass
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public InnerClass(int num) => Value = num;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) => OuterClassList.Add(new OuterClass(new Random().Next(0, 1000)));

private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var values = from o in OuterClassList select o.InnerObject.Value;//you always have it, then you don't need InnerClassList I think.
    foreach (var value in values)
        MessageBox.Show(value.ToString());
}
```